How to add a strip for a date to a DevExpress Chart control?
I need to highlight weekends and holidays on a DevExpress chart control. According to documentation  I need to provide min-max value range, but it highlights the area between those values. E.g. If I need to highlight that 2025.01.01 is a holiday, I would need to provide range from 1st of January to 2nd of January and that would highlight area between those argument points, but I need to highlight that date - i.e. I would need to highlight from ~middle of day before to middle, so that it's clear that value is in the higlighted area (and not on the edge of it)
I've tried DevExpress documented steps but didn't find to adjust it to fit my needs
One workaround comes to mind is to add an additional serie with a secondary Y axis and set it as a Bar serie and make it fill all the vertical space, but I'm hoping to get a cleaner way to handle this.
Seems like a quite common thing to hightlight holidays in a chart that displays date based data
Here is a code sample with the chart control


Maybe could solve using secondary X axis that would have points that match points between dates, so I could define Strip for those points. Will update the ticket when I have checked that
